# :ter source ~/.zshrc return executing job failed: No such file or directory

Tags: terminal, macos

I have tried the solutions suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11415428/terminal-vim-not-loading-zshrc) but none worked.

The issue is easily reproducible, just run `:ter source ~/.zshrc`

No special requirements for *.zsrch* and the *.vimrc* files, they can be empty (but I tried to add `set shell=zsh` and set `shell=zsh\ -i` in the *.vimrc* as suggested in the link I posted).

However, if you run `:ter`, wait for the terminal to open, and then run `source ~/.zshrc` from the terminal buffer everything works fine.

I am running on Mac OS X Ventura and I tried with both the shipped Vim 9.0 and MacVim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word `source` is not an external command; it is a shell builtin. Running `:terminal source file` attempts to find a program `source` in `$PATH` and give it the argument `file`.

If your `$SHELL` is `zsh`, there should be no need to manually `source ~/.zshrc` after a bare `:terminal` unless you have modified it in the meantime: `$ZDOTDIR/.zshrc` (default if unset: `$HOME`) is read as long as the shell is interactive.